# Is it possible to modify exported variable after it is exported

Tags: node.js, node-modules

i'm still new to node.js and i'm trying to create and export my database connection with [mysqljs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql).

I'm having a trouble because if something happens like the database crash or a network problem, the connection needs to be re-created. I can't figure out how to udpate the previously exported connection to my app.

Is there a way to update an object exported by the module like i did ?

Am i missing something or using module.exports in the wrong way ?

I think it would be possible to use a function or a constructor but i would have to edit every module that currently uses my dbh variable.

```
var reconnection_interval = 5000;
var db_config = {
    host : "localhost",
    user : "root",
    password : "",
    database : "test"
};

var dbh;

function handleDisconnect(conn)
{
  conn.on('error', function(err)
  {
    // If the error is not fatal, we just ignore it.
    if(!err.fatal){return;}
    else
    {
        logger.error('Database error : '+err);
        logger.info('Trying to reconnect in '+reconnection_interval/1000+'s');

        // Destroying old connection.
        dbh = undefined;

        // Creating a new connection and trying to reconnect every <reconnection_interval>
        setTimeout(function(){
          dbh = mysql.createConnection(db_config);
          handleDisconnect(dbh);
          dbh.connect();

          // I want to update the module.exports value, so it becomes the new connection
          module.exports = dbh;

        }, reconnection_interval);
    } 
  });
}


dbh = mysql.createConnection(db_config);
handleDisconnect(dbh);
dbh.connect();
logger.info("Connected to database.");


module.exports = dbh;
```

Comment: No, you can't really "export asynchronously". Once your require it, it is evaluated once through, then exported objects returned to the caller. Any async action will not be reflected. You could create a wrapper class to handle a connection internally.

Comment: @Li357 Could you show me an example or a sample ? I don't see how to do and use that in JS. I'm familiar to OOP but i have never seen anything like that in node.js so far. People seem to go the module way as much as possible.